# Ensuring user input of date is in (MM/YY)

Tags: c++, regex, pattern-matching

I need to verify that user input of a date is in the format of MM/YYYY.

I have decided to use the regcomp and regexec functions as my solution. 

**The problem is:** No matter the input the output is **always Match**. And the **return value of the call to regexec is 0**, indicating a match even if there truly isn't one. 
Why is this happening?

 I know the regex I am using will match 99/99, but I am first trying to figure out why it is matching ABCDE as well. 

Below is the code in question:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <regex.h>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
        int rs;
        regex_t preg;
        size_t     nmatch = 1;
        regmatch_t pmatch[1];
        char * pattern = "^((0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))\/(\d{4})$";
        char inputDate[8];

//Loop until user input matches regex
        cout << "Enter Date: ";
        cin.getline(inputDate, 8);

        if (0 != (rs = regcomp(&preg, pattern, 0))) {
                perror("ERROR IN REGCOMP");
                exit(1);
        }

        if (0 != (rs = regexec(&preg, inputDate, nmatch, pmatch, 0))) {
                 printf("Failed to match '%s' with '%s',returning %d.\n", inputDate, pattern, rs);
                perror("ERROR IN REGEXEC");
        }
        else
                printf("Match");

        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

At first your regex must be `"^[0-9][0-9]\\/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$"` to match `MM/YYYY`.

At second you never compiles it. You compile inputDate.

```
regcomp(&preg, inputDate, REG_EXTENDED)
```

Try to compile your pattern:

```
regcomp(&preg, pattern, REG_EXTENDED)
```

Comment: Good answers I am writing up a full answer, but I changed the regular expression patter to ^((0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))\/(\d{4})$ to match MM/YYYY
But it isn't working. Where is the error?

Comment: It's still return 0? Can you give output from terminal? And why you compiles pattern twice?

Comment: I just noticed that. I removed the extra regcomp.

Comment: With the new pattern, Receiving error in regexec: undefined. Am I not escaping it properly?

Comment: Maybe / must be \/ to be properly escaped. Also your new regex doesn't match something like 04/1984. Try something simpler like ^(\\d{2})\\/(\\d{4})$

Comment: Actually, also receive an undefined error with "^(\\d{2})\\/(\\d{4})$"
I am sure the problem I am having is improper escaping?

Comment: Wait a minute, why wouldn't "^((0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))\/(\d{4})$"
match 04/1984?
I also tried backspacing the '(' and ')'
"^\\(\\d{2})\\/\\(\\d{4}\\)$";

Answer (score 1):

Remove `$` from the end of the pattern and try this:

```
if (0 != (rs = regcomp(&preg, pattern, 0))) {
    perror("ERROR IN REGCOMP");
    exit(1);
}

if (0 != (rs = regexec(&preg, inputDate, nmatch, pmatch, 0))) {
    printf("Failed to match '%s' with '%s',returning %d.\n",
    inputDate, pattern, rs);
    perror("ERROR IN REGEXEC");
}
else 
{
    printf("Match");
}
```